# Connecting To A Git Repository On A Linux Server Through C#

Tags: c#, git, asp.net-mvc-3, version-control

I am wondering if it is possible to connect to a git server that is hosted on another server (running Linux) through a C# ASP.NET application.  I am only looking for reading capabilities to be able to display information of that git repository in the ASP.NET application.

Comment: Heh, Lunix: http://www.adequacy.org/stories/2001.12.2.42056.2147.html

Answer (score 1):

[SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx) is really easy to use and i've never had any problems with it, it will let you connect via SSH and run commands, or use SCP to copy files from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply stream the output that a local msysgit command would return.